# Download file from ADLS to local file system through R has connection error

Tags: r, curl, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using the AzureR packages to access Azure Data Lake Storage from RStudio.
I setup the connections with the script below:

```
library(AzureRMR)
library(AzureStor)

# setup connections
az <- az_rm$new(tenant="my_tenant_id",
                app="my_app_id",
                password="my_password")

sub <- az$get_subscription("my_subscription_id")
rg <- sub$get_resource_group("my_resource_group_name")
stor <- rg$get_resource(type="Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                        name="my_datalake_account_name")

stor$do_operation("listKeys", http_verb="POST")
```

The connection works well and I got the following result:

```
attr(,"status")
[1] 200
```

Then I upload file to and download file from the ADLS file system with the script below:

```
fs <- adls_filesystem(
  "https://my_datalake_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/my_file_system_name", 
  key="my_key"
)
# create new directory
create_adls_dir(fs, "/newdir")
upload_adls_file(
  fs, src = "I:/lookup.csv",
  dest = "/newdir/lookup.csv"
)
download_adls_file(
  fs, src = "/newdir/lookup.csv",
  dest = "J:/lookup.csv"
)
```

The upload works good, while the download show the following errors:

```
Connection error, retrying (1 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (2 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (3 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (4 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (5 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (6 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (7 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (8 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (9 of 10)
Connection error, retrying (10 of 10)
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Send failure: Connection was reset
```

Right now I have two servers that I can work on, however the goal is to switch to the new server and eliminate the old server. The script works good on the old server, the CSV file is very small so the upload and download finish within a sec. However, on the new server, the upload works good while the download failed. Any ideas about what might cause this issue? I'm wondering if there is any system setting that are different between the two servers but I'm really new to the Data Lake. Any help would be very appreciate!

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) check that your new server doesn't have a firewall issue; 2) check that you have the right permissions on your J: drive

Answer (score 1):

Since the same script is working on the old server , I think if I were you i could have focused the path "J:/lookup.csv" . Is J: a physical drive or FIle share .

Anyways I could have tested with something more obvious like c or d drive and test that part .